# Create Powershell Object From Loop Containing Multiple Users

Tags: arrays, loops, object, powershell, hashtable

I need to create a Powershell object, array or hash table to store a list of users and assorted details, these are extracted from a CSV file and located using Get-ADUser. As below:

```
$userList = Import-CSV $CSVInputFile
$users = @{}
Foreach ($csvUser in $userList)
{
    $userSearchString = $csvUser | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
    $currentUser = (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $userSearchString} `
        -Properties PasswordExpired,PasswordLastSet,EmailAddress |
            Where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"})

    If ($currentUser.EmailAddress -ne $null)
    {
        $currentUserEmailString = $csvUser | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddress
        $currentUserEmailString = ($currentUserEmailString -as [string])
        $currentUser.EmailAddress = $currentUserEmailString
    }

    $Users = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        DistinguishedName = $currentUser.DistinguishedName
        EmailAddress = $currentUser.EmailAddress    
        Enabled = $currentUser.Enabled          
        GivenName = $currentUser.GivenName       
        Name = $currentUser.Name
        PasswordExpired = $currentUser.PasswordExpired
        PasswordLastSet = $currentUser.PasswordLastSet
        SamAccountName = $currentUser.SamAccountName
        Surname = $currentUser.Surname
    }
    $Users
}
```

How can I add the details of each user for each iteration of the loop to the object.

I want to end up with an object containing the details of a number of users, same as the output directly from Get-ADUser:

```
Name        SamAccountName EmailAddress                    
----        -------------- ------------                    
User1       user1      user1@domain.com    
User2       user2      user2@domain.com                         
User3       user3      user3@domain.com
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I'm missing the point on this but I see you are building a custom object right in your loop. The only issue I do see is you are not keeping the results after each loop. Rather you are destroying the objects history.

I would change the declaration of `$users` to an array `$users = @()` and instead of populating a user hashtable into users add the current object into the array. You will then have an array of hashtables:

```
$Users += New-Object PSObject -Property @{...
```

Then you could the `$Users` output line outside the loop and you will have the whole thing. Then you could just output to a `Select` to get the output you desire.

```
$Users | Select-Object name,SamAccountName,EmailAddress
```

There is a potential major drawback of this approach though. When using `+=` on arrays a new array is created and resized for the new element and the old array is discarded. This has huge performance implications for larger arrays.

---

An even better way to approach this would be to leverage the pipeline. This would be a performance boost when you have larger user groups.

```cs
Import-CSV $CSVInputFile | ForEach-Object{
    $userSearchString = $_.SamAccountName
    $currentUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $userSearchString} `
        -Properties PasswordExpired,PasswordLastSet,EmailAddress |
            Where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"}

    If ($currentUser.EmailAddress -ne $null){
        $currentUser.EmailAddress = $_.EmailAddress
    }

    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        DistinguishedName = $currentUser.DistinguishedName
        # ..... truncated 
        Surname = $currentUser.Surname
    }
}
```

Now you could send that to something like `Export-CSV` or just save it into a variable. Your options are open now. `[pscustomobject][ordered]` are type accelerators available in PowerShell v3.0+

Comment: That's so simple, why didn't I think of that!

Works a treat, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Define an $users as Array

```
$users = @()
```

and append the New-Object into $Users.

```
$Users += New-Object
```

Comment: I was so close to having this before you

Comment: I wrote only 4 lines in my answer. I think you beat me.

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe both of you guys got in before me! Oh well.
Hope this helps anyway.

```
$userList = Import-CSV $CSVInputFile
$users = @()
Foreach ($csvUser in $userList)
{
$userSearchString = $csvUser | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$currentUser = (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $userSearchString} `
    -Properties PasswordExpired,PasswordLastSet,EmailAddress |
        Where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"})

If ($currentUser.EmailAddress -ne $null)
{
    $currentUserEmailString = $csvUser | Select -ExpandProperty EmailAddress
    $currentUserEmailString = ($currentUserEmailString -as [string])
    $currentUser.EmailAddress = $currentUserEmailString
}

#clears the properties of the previous object and starts collecting properties
$UserObj = New-Object PSObject
    Add-Member -InputObject $UserObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DistinguishedName" -Value $($currentUser.DistinguishedName)
    Add-Member -InputObject $UserObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "EmailAddress" -Value $($currentUser.EmailAddress)    
    Add-Member -InputObject $UserObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Enabled" -Value $($currentUser.Enabled)
    Add-Member -InputObject $UserObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "GivenName" -Value $($currentUser.GivenName)     
    Add-Member -InputObject $UserObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UserName" -Value $($currentUser.Name)
    Add-Member -InputObject $UserObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PasswordExpired" -Value $($currentUser.PasswordExpired)
    Add-Member -InputObject $UserObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PasswordLastSet" -Value $($currentUser.PasswordLastSet)
    Add-Member -InputObject $UserObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SamAccountName" -Value $($currentUser.SamAccountName) 
    Add-Member -InputObject $UserObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Surname" -Value $($currentUser.Surname)

#saves the properties in an array that exists outside of the loop to preserve information beyond one interation
$users += $UserObj
 }

 $users | Format-Table -Property UserName,SamAccountName,EmailAddress
```